# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile-ajax

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
                <title>webservices example </title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                type:"GET",
                            url:"http://shoperola.com/Restaurant/foodysrest/sample",
                                 crossDomain: true,
                                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                                 dataType: "json",
xhrFields: {

       withCredentials: true
  },
             beforeSend: function (request) {

request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ", "*")
},
                                 success: function(data) {
                                                alert(data);
                                                },
                                 error: function(data) {
                                alert("Error in Processing-----" + data.status);
                                          }
                                });
                        });

                </script>
            </head>
        </html>
```

" XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://shoperola.com/Restaurant/foodysrest/sample?{}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://:8088' is therefore not allowed access".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to perform `XMLHttpRequest(AJAX)` to another domain.

This is restricted due to security reasons.

for more details see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Do you mean that the server is not configured to allow this? because in the client side, I think this is implemented as suggested in CORS, using xhrFields with credentials, and setting the header with ACAO.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing semicolon on line:

request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ", "*")