# How to debug "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, spring-boot, angular-ui-router, cors

I am getting this error shown on browser console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9009' is therefore not allowed access.

The environment I am using are:

- **Backend**- Spring Boot
- **Front End**- Angularjs
- **Web Server**- Grunt

On server, I am already defining headers in request and response as:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE,PUT");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,Authorization, Content-Type");

        if (httpRequest.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
            return;
        }
}
```

I already found this question on this link [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973622/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource) but couldn't find the appropriate solution.

Here is the browser network image:

[image]

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but: 1) be careful with the "*" when you move this to production, 2) please show us the headers that pass the wire when you make this call (F12 in your browser and then network will show them)

Comment: I have uploaded the image

Comment: This is confusing. Aren't you setting the headers in the response ? Your trace shows them in the request

Answer (score 1):

Your server should add the proper CORS headers for preflight/actual CORS requests. I wouldn't recommend implementing your own Filter, since this is a rather complex specification.

As of 4.2, Spring Framework supports CORS with a global configuration or with a Filter - [see this blog post for more information](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework).

If you're using Spring Boot, version 1.3.0 (to be released soon) [will integrate this support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-cors).

Answer (score 0):

Your Filter is right, You should include your filter as a component and put it where it can be scanned by spring

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to also make an update in your angular code to allow CORS via AJAX.

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

If the above doesn't work, you may need to also add the following:

```
myApp.all('/*', function (request, response, next) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
    next();    
});
```

As noted by @Marged you want to be cautious about the "*" and I would highly recommend replacing that with your domain(s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) on your web server. Please refer to [this resource](https://spring.io/understanding/CORS).

You need to set your response header to:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

[This link](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) has all the info needed to set CORS

Enabling CORS for all domain is not a good practice, so you should restrict it when everything is up and running.

### Another workaround is to have a separate API for curl request

Call a URL in your own API and access the data using your server side with cURL or something. I have a current working project with same situation (Laravel + AngularJs).

My sample code for the remote auth check with cURL request.

Code is in Laravel-PHP format, I hope you can convert to the language you are working on.

### Requester function:

```
public function curlRequester($url,$fields)
    {
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        $result_json_decoded = json_decode($result, true);


        return $result_json_decoded;
    }
```

### Controller function

```
public function login()
{

    // set POST params
    $fields = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );
    $url = 'http://www.this-is-api-url.com/login';

    $result = $this->curl->curlRequester($url,$fields);

    return response()->json($result);

}
```

### Angular request function

```
$scope.authCheck = function(){

        $http({
            url:'http://www.our-project-url/login',
            method:"post",
            data:{"username": "rameez", "password":"rameezrami"}
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            if(response.status==1){
                $location.path("/homepage");
            }else if(response.status==0){
                $scope.login_error_message_box = true;
                $scope.login_error_message_text =response.message;
            }

        });

    }
```

Comment: Yes i followed that but couldn't find the error where its lagging.

Comment: hi.. from the network image u posted it seems you haven't set CORS ACCESS HEADER in server side.