# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error (angularjs + rest)

Tags: angularjs, rest

Using `angularjs` to write data in another machine's file failed:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Setting:

**`anjular js` client**:

```
$http.post(url, settingData)
```

**`rest` server side**:

```
    return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObject.toString())
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
            .allow("OPTIONS")
            .build();
```

[image]

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821753/jquery-xml-error-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-req and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20973800/218152

Comment: I am not very understanding, could you give me the detail information setting?

Comment: please dump the contents of your browsers NET tab to show request and response (if any) details

Comment: Don't set the CORS headers in the resource method. [Use a filter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34412067/2587435). The resource method is never hit because it is designed for POST request, while the preflight is an OPTIONS request.

Comment: could you add what server are you using? for example, apache, nodejs + epxress, etc. This is a CORS problem and the solution should be made on the server side. for NodeJS+express you can use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue) from @jvandemo